# Regex: как выбрать real path из строки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Не могу победить до конца регулярку. Нужно из строки выбрать группы: datetime, текст внутри квадратных скобок и путь (исключить имя файла) из подстроки.

Пример строки:

```
2023-10-26 03:06:55,136 WARN  [TSSS_NSSS-SIB] done ip 10.33.22.22 f '/mnt/data/DD/DD/A/sds/tdf/DDdf-fdfd-dfdf_dfdf_3433343.txt' t '/DDdf-fdfd-dfdf_dfdf_3433343.txt' sz 3507
```

Вот регулярка: `(.*)(\sWARN\s{2}\[)(.*)(\]\s)(done[^\']+\')`

Не получается сказать, что нужно дальше выбрать все от первого вхождения "/" до последнего вхождения "/" в подстроке с путем.
В итоге из этой строки нужно выбрать группами:

```
2023-10-26 03:06:55
TSSS_NSSS-SIB
/mnt/data/DD/DD/A/sds/tdf/
```

Comment: Какой язык? Регулярки различаются в зависимости от языка

Comment: С++, Rust, PHP. Я разберусь в логике.  Делаю на Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из задачи убрал кучу лишних групп и не только. Вот:

**UPDATED: Обновил для Rust**

```regex
([^,]*)[^\[]*\[(.*)\][^']+'([^']*)'
```

https://regex101.com/r/57lg9l/2

**UPDATED2**: Если надо только если WARN и done:

```regex
([^,]*),\d*\sWARN\s*[^\[]*\[(.*)\]\sdone\s[^']+'([^']*)'
```

**UPDATED3**: Не цепляя имя файла:

```regex
([^,]*)[^\[]*\[(.*)\][^']+'([^']*)/.*\..*'
```

https://regex101.com/r/57lg9l/3

Comment: Он цепляет весь путь, внутри одинарных кавычек. А нужен путь до последнего слеша без имени файла. Как ему сказать до последнего вхождения слеша?

Comment: @Dima обновил ответ

Comment: @Dima Извиняюсь, что изначально не увидел это в вопросе) Подумал что надо без второй строки в одинарных кавычках

Answer (score 0):

```
(^.+?),.+?\[(.+?)].+?'(\/(?:[^']+?\/)+)
```